# P(a and b) + P(a and not(b)) = P(a)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What would be an easy way of proving
$$ P(a\land b) + P(a\land \lnot b) = P(a) $$?

I think I managed something by applying the inclusion-exclusion principle in the form $ P(x) + P(y) = P(x \lor y) + P(x \land y)$ to the left-hand side (with $x=a \land b$ and $y=a \land \lnot b$) and then the $x\land y$ is always false and the $x\lor y$ seems to reduce to just $a$, but isn't there a more straightforward proof?

Comment: Wait.. I think I do not fully understand how these probabilities work.. I thought that if I get $P(something always false)$, this is always 0, but this is not true, is it?

Comment: the problem is with P(a and not(b))

Comment: It is an axiom of probability that if $P(B \land C)=0$ then $P(B \lor C)=P(B)+P(C)$, and similarly for larger finite sums and countably infinite sums of disjoint events.  In a sense this is what you used.

Comment: @FarrukhAtaev what kind of problem exactly :)?

Comment: This is an instance of [the law of total probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: @Henry Oh, yes, but if $B\land C = false$ (always), does that mean that the probability is always 0? Sadly, I do not have that much knowledge about probabilities.

Comment: Use venn diagram.

Comment: It is true that $P(Impossible Event)=0$. It is the opposite direction that is not true, i.e. $P(A)=0$ does not necessarily mean $A$ is impossible, because there can be an infinite number of such probability-zero events that together have a non-zero probability.

Comment: Another axiom is that there is an event of probability $1$ and there are none with greater probability.  Yet another says probabilities are non-negative. Considering the complement of the event of probability $1$ and addition means the non-event has probability $0$

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - but "there can be an infinite number of such probability-zero events that together have a non-zero probability" would require an unaccountably infinite number of such events

Comment: @Henry See the definition of [almost never](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely). The traditional example is of a dart board. Every point of the board has a probability of 0 of being hit by a dart. And yet, some point gets hit.

Comment: nevermind, the OP was stated correctly. In a set notation: $P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\setminus B)$

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've managed to find a formal proof (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Total_Probability_Theorem), using @mrp 's remark that this is an instance of the law of total probability.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a circle. Let this be universal set . Now draw tow small intersecting circles in this circle. Let these represent $P (A),P (B) $. The area common to them is $P (A n B) $ . The area excluding $P (B)$ is $P (B') $. Now this $P (B'),P (A) $ has area common which is not common with $P (B) $. Thus  from diagram its clear that $P (A n B)+P (A n B')=P (A) $. I was going to add the diagram but max size is restricting me from uploading it. Hope you get what I am saying.

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to draw it and it seems interesting.

Comment: Still, something is not clear to me: this diagram to me seems to prove that $(A\land B) \cup (A\land B^c) = A$ (for sets). How are these diagrams applied to probabilities? I apologize, I am not very familiar with probabilities.

Comment: They are not applied to probabilities. Just a way to make problems easier rather than learning too many identities.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways of seeing this:

**Point of view of sets:**

In terms of the axiom of Finite additivity:
$$P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) \forall A, B \in F, A ∩ B = ∅$$

That's what @Archis Welankar tried to explain you.

**Point of view of logic:**

In the point of view of logic the equivalent to the axiom of Finite additivity is:

$$P(A \land B) = P(A) + P(B), \forall A \in S, B \in S$$ such that A and B are
logically incompatible.

In terms of logic you have that:

$$a=a \land (b \lor \lnot b)=(a \land b)\lor (a \land \lnot b)$$

As you can see $(a \land b)$ and $(a \land \lnot b)$ are logically incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

From the kolmogorov axioms we know $P(B \cap B^\mathsf{c}) = P(\Omega )$. For any subset $A$ of $\Omega$: 
$P(A \cap \Omega)=P(A)$